# My Jmeter script is passed even though code turned off on production

Tags: jmeter

I have created scripts for smoke testing insurance quotes on jmeter.
Recently code has been turned off on production.
Now even though the code is off when I run my script my test gets passed.
Manually I am unable to perform the same steps in the production.
So what could be the issue with my script?

Comment: More detail, please?

Comment: Transactions we are performing
1] locate existing quote
2] Rate the quote
3] Verify premium and logout

When doing manually we get an error when quote is retrieved in application as the application code is turned off
But when running jmeter script all these steps get executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't do any checks on the response body, it assumes that the request is successful if the [HTTP Status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is below 400.

So if your HTTP Request samplers return HTTP Status code between 0 and 399 - it will be "green".

You can consider adding i.e. [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and configure it to check presence (or absence) of a specific text in the response body, this way you will be able to conditionally fail samplers if the expected text will not be present.

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/)